# My php calculation is not displaying the result

Tags: php

I have a very silly question. I am pulling the total of income and expenses from mysql and later i want to subtract expense from income. For some reason the result is not whats left over instead it shows the income figure - expense figure.

the code is below

```
function total_by_type_between_dates($type, $start, $end){
    global $uc_con;
    $start  = strtotime ($start);
    $end    = strtotime ($end);
    $sql    = "SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM account WHERE `time` > $start && `time` < $end &&  `type` = '$type'";
    $result = $uc_con->query($sql);
    $row    = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $total  = number_format((float)$row['total'], 2, '.', '');
    echo $total;
}

function total_expense_between_dates($start, $end){
    global $uc_con;
    $start  = strtotime ($start);
    $end    = strtotime ($end);
    $sql    = "SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM account WHERE `time` > $start && `time` < $end && `type` != 'income' && `type` != 'mileage'";
    $result = $uc_con->query($sql);
    $row    = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $total  = number_format((float)$row['total'], 2, '.', '');
    return $total;
}

echo total_by_type_between_dates('income', $date_begining, $date_ending)-total_expense_between_dates($date_begining, $date_ending);
```

weirdly the result is showing as follow: `2770.69-407.42` instead of `2363.29`

Could anyone tell me what may be causing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `total_by_type_between_dates` function is echo'ing its result instead of returning it. So your

```
echo total_by_type_between_dates('income', $date_begining, $date_ending)-total_expense_between_dates($date_begining, $date_ending);
```

is effectively

```
echo total_by_type_between_dates('income', $date_begining, $date_ending);
echo null-total_expense_between_dates($date_begining, $date_ending);
```

and the `null` gets treated as 0 in a numeric context, hence the result you see: `2770.69-407.42`

Change

```
echo $total;
```

in `total_by_type_between_dates` to

```
return $total;
```

and the code will work as expected.

Stripped down [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FsmbA)

Comment: I knew it was something very silly. I dont know how i missed it. Thank you.